# What type of transformer should I use to convert 24VAC to 12VAC (or vice versa)?

Tags: power-supply, transformer

I'm working on a project that combines a board from an electric organ with one of those cheap Chinese tube amps. [The board](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/328676/is-this-negative-regulator-really-meant-to-be-an-inverted-positive-regulator?noredirect=1&lq=1) requires +12V/-15V DC and the amp requires 12VAC.

I don't want to power the final product with two wall warts, because that would be fiddly and annoying.

The amp converts its 12VAC to ±30VAC internally, and my first thought was to power the amp off a 12VAC wall wart, then tap off the ±30 on the amp's board and power a 7812 and 7915 off of this (rectified first of course). But connecting them up causes a huge voltage drop, so it seems that this isn't going to work.

The current idea I'm working with is to power the whole project off a 24VAC wall wart, which will run the 7812/7915 combo fine, and also can step down at 2:1 to 12VAC for the amp.

My problem is that I can't find a 2:1 transformer suitable, but it seems impossible that such a thing doesn't exist. (The only 2:1 transformers I can find are huge, built to take 240V to 120V. This would work in principle but it would bring up the size/weight of the project by at least an order of magnitude which isn't ideal, to say the least.)

I bought some of these [78604-1C](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Murata-Power-Solutions/78604-1C/?qs=JYcnCVuwx%2FLhsz%252bFdmo%2FyA==) but they fry on 12VAC+ input. (The datasheet I have isn't forthcoming about a maximum voltage, which I am also confused about)

- Is there a specific thing I should be searching for that will turn my 24VAC to 12VAC in a small package?
- Or, is there some other way of solving this problem that explains why this type of transformer is so hard to find?

Comment: You mention "a huge voltage drop" - have you checked the current capability of the relevant components?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I haven't done the exact calculations, but I do assume that the drop means I'm exceeding the current capability of the amp's circuitry; hence wanting to change tack and power the amp and board separately from 24VAC, rather than power the amp from 12VAC and then power the board from the amp.

Comment: You can't use 7812 with AC

Comment: @HandyHowie I'm rectifying it before it gets to the 7812— I'll edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: Your pulse transformers may be happy on 12VAC ... as long as it's at about 100kHz, not 50/60Hz. Their primary inductance is stated, and way too low to protect them at low frequencies - no wonder they fried.

Comment: @BrianDrummond ahh, ok. I am new to… pretty much all of this, and didn't know that "pulse" meant "high frequency". Now I do!

Comment: Why can´t you get everything from a single 12VAC supply? Once rectified that will give you around 18V DC - more than enough for the 7812 and just enough for a 7915. Or use a 12-0-12 transformer with 2 diodes and center tap, rather than a bridge to save on the extra diode voltage drop.

Comment: @F.Bloggs that's how I'd expect it to work, but I see 13VAC before the rectifier bridge and 11.3VDC after

Comment: Have you add a smoothing capacitor after the bridge? That should bring the (average) DC voltage to around 18V. Or gain (slightly) more voltage with a full-wave rectifier, center-tapped design - although that needs a more expensive tranformer.

Comment: @F.Bloggs ah! That's what I was missing— 100uF brings it up substantially, so I imagine 1000uF will get it to 18V…

Comment: What is it now giving you? A 1000uF capacitor won´t bring the (open circuit) voltage up very much more, but will help under load, ie smooth out the ripple more than a 100uF. And, sorry - half asleep here -  you will need another winding for the -15V/7915 supply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66118/discussion-between-buildsucceeded-and-f-bloggs).

Comment: @F.Bloggs What do you mean, another winding?

Comment: Ok, basics: Do you know what current you actually need? You say 'Chinese tube amp' - is that an actual amp - or a pre-amplifier (like the 'Little Bear' units)? I just looked again at the link to your previous post and see that the other board uses 800mA fuses, so maximum total draw will most probably be around 1,5A. This:  http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/toroidal-transformers/6718956/ will give you just over 2A/winding, so as long as the amp doesn´t draw too much, will be ok. Use 1 winding, with bridge & condensor to supply the 7812 and the other for the 7915, as per your 1st post.

Comment: @F.Bloggs it is a preamp like [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Z-Tube-6N3-Buffer-Audio-Pre-amplifier-Pre-AMP-Kit-For-DIY-/110577554717?epid=853282443&hash=item19beef951d:m:mkqZwJAjQK-1KyuiKZrj6OA). You think it's not possible to rectify & smooth the 12VAC enough to power a 7915 properly after all?

Comment: It will be borderline as the 78/79 regulators need a couple of volts more on the input than output to work properly. A 2 x 15V transformer would be better, but that depends on the preamp. Those units rectify the (nominal) AC input and then double the voltage to power the valve. What voltage are the capacitors? If there is some margin (eg 50V devices), then just use a 2 x 15V transformer for the project.  :)

Comment: Here:  http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/toroidal-transformers/2237901/

Comment: @F.Bloggs adding the 1000uF cap gives me 18V rectified, but the 7915 still only outputs 3.1V or so. Re-checking the datasheet the 7915 wants -23V in so even 15VAC * 1.414 = 21VDC wouldn't be enough… looks like the 24V-based answer is going to be the way to go here.

Comment: Is that 3.1V, or -3.1V? Are you sure you connected the device correctly? The positive of the bridge must go to the 7915 earth, ie 1st pin, then the negative to the 2nd pin. -18V should be fine for the device to work correctly.

Comment: @F.Bloggs I must have it hooked up wrong as it gives a low positive voltage when fed 24V as well. I'll ask another question although this is probably some head-smackingly simple thing.

Comment: Question about the 7915's behavior in this case: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331998/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-this-voltage-regulator

Comment: Ok, looks like you got your answer. Rail voltages are defined relative to ground!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcsHBF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) 12 to 24 transformation without isolation. (b) Fully isolated 12 to 24 V transformation.*

Transformers are very flexible and versatile.

> My problem is that I can't find a 2:1 transformer suitable, but it seems impossible that such a thing doesn't exist.

You should be able to find a dual 120V:12V transformer quite easily and use this with the mains side disconnected. If you feed 12 V in on the secondary you will get mains voltage on the primary but you just need to make sure that it is properly isolated. i.e., You don't have to use it.

In Figure 1b I have sketched just one of many arrangements that are possible depending on the transformers available. Here we are paralleling  the 12 V "primaries" and series connecting the "secondaries".

Watch your VA rating overall. Also watch your winding current and make sure you don't exceed the design value.

Comment: Something like http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/pcb-transformers/1213841/?

Comment: That's the idea. Note that on that one each secondary is rated at only 3 VA. You have to do the maths. See also their [good old-fashioned versions](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/power-supplies-transformers/transformers/chassis-mounting-transformers/?applied-dimensions=4293338397,4293333070).

Comment: There used to be some transformer kits - typically with a 120 / 240 primary and the secondary bobbin left empty, laminations, frame and bolts. RS used to sell them but don't seem to anymore.  If you could find one of these you could cut the primary windings out and make your own 12 / 24 transformer.

Comment: I am not an expert, but isn't this going to get you the exact same result as simply removing XFMR1 from the schematic, and just connecting the mains to XFMR2?  It'll require XFMR2 to have a higher VA rating, but it's (A) simpler, and (B) doesn't have a couple of unconnected wires with mains voltage on them.  Point (B) is less of an issue in the US, but having grown up in the UK, and having had exactly one 240 VAC shock from the mains in my lifetime, I have a **very** healthy respect for mains voltages,

Comment: Thanks for making me look at my answer again. There was an error in Figure 1b which I think I've fixed. It's most of a year since I answered this so I don't remember my thought process. I did point out that the mains terminals have to be properly isolated.

Answer (score 1):

If you find a transformer for power grid voltage with two secondary winding for 24 and 12 V AC, you may use it as a 24 to 12 V transformer. Just leave the higher voltage winding unconnected and use the two former secondary windings as new primary and secondary.

A 240 to 120 V transformer could be used as a 24 to 12 V transformer only for very low currents. It has too many windings (10 times too much) and the wire diameter is much to small.

The best solution is to use one single transformer only with secondary windings for both 24 and 12 V AC. You get both needed voltages from that single transformer.