# What am I doing wrong with this voltage regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have this to try to get a regulated -15V DC:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCSma6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But my 7915 outputs a (positive) low voltage in the 1-3V region.

I've checked the input voltages and they are good. I've tried two 7915s and they operate the same way. I've tried a higher input voltage and get the same behavior.

Datasheet excerpt:
[image: Datasheet excerpt]

What am I doing wrong?

Update: pics (the 7915 is the reg on the right)
[image: Breadboard overhead]

[image: Closeup]

Comment: Strange that you measured positive voltage. Do you have a picture of your setup? Have you triple checked pinout? What's the voltage at the input of the regulator?

Comment: –38VDC at the input when powered by 24V AC; -18V when powered by 12V AC

Comment: Check datasheet for minimum load requirement.

Comment: @buildsucceeded 7915 has a maximum (well, minimum really) input voltage of -35VDC, so you should not run it on -38VDC. Also consider that at -35V input, you're dropping 20V. At that drop a 50mA load would burn a whole watt in heat at the regulator, which would (according to the Tj-a specs) increase the case temperature by 60degC above ambient.

Comment: @replete even if the datasheet shows only its figures under a 5-mA minimum load, your suggestion is wrong. 1) you could never have a POSITIVE voltage with respect to ground, unless he's doing what I answered. 2) The internal resistors of the 7915 already act as load. 3) I have tested right now a 7915, and it gives exactly -15V under no load. 4) In fact, there is no "minimum load requirement of xxx mA" requirement.

Comment: @next-hack: I was addressing the failed measurement in general, whether he was measuring with the leads reversed is up to him to say not for us to guess.  Minimum load requirement is a typical attribute of voltage regulators and varies from device to device. If the device is insufficiently loaded, it won't regulate. He hasn't linked the datasheet for his device so we can't say for sure. Implying that the internal resistors act as a sufficient load is nonsense. Read some datasheets. You are assuming all 7915s of all generations from all manufacturers are equal in this regard. That is untrue.

Comment: @replete a bit of sense would also tell you that you can't have a positive voltage with respect to ground, when the highest potential is actually the ground...  And this does not depend on the manufacturer or whatever. Won't it regulate? Ok, it will have a voltage between Vin and ground. NOT positive. The Occam's razor would also suggest why he's measuring a positive 3V...

Comment: Don't insult people, it only makes you look bad. The OP posted a schematic without a load so I posted a comment - not an answer - about the load's importance. That should not be controversial. You are jumping to conclusions about how the OP made his measurements, just wait for clarification. You need to understand that an insufficiently loaded regulator can oscillate. Don't look for the words "minimum load" in the datasheet, look for the minimum current at which the device is specified. An insufficient load means the device is being used out of spec.

Comment: @replete I'm sorry of having offended anyone, I didn't really intended to (and honestly I can't find any offensive/insulting language, still I beg your pardon). Anyway, even if it oscillated, I can hardly figure out how would the DC voltage go to a positive value, with respect to ground, when the ground is actually the highest potential. A positive voltage would also make the electrolytic quite not happy. But from the closeup, they are wired correctly.

Comment: @next-hack No worries, we are talking past each other. I have no problem with what you are saying, the point is that the question is "What am I doing wrong with this voltage regulator?" and running it out of spec wrt load is wrong hence my comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's likely you're measuring the voltage between the yellow and blue wires, on the bottom right part of the board.

However, the closeup of your 7915 shows that the blue wire is the central terminal of the 7915, which, unlike 7815, it's the input and not the ground.

Therefore you're measuring \$V_{OUT}-V_{IN}\$, which is about \$-15\ V-(-18\ V) = 3\ V\$.

You should measure the voltage between the yellow (output) and the red wires (ground) that are connected to the 7915.

Comment: Absolutely correct (and facepalm on my part) — measuring from the actual ground, and not the input, gives -14.98V! Thank you for your help!